# ActiveAdmin: display parameter of object selected in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am not very familiar with ActiveAdmin or rails in general, so sorry if I use some incorrect phrasing.

I have a model for an Athlete, which has an attribute "notes".  This is described in the `permit_params` of the athlete.rb.

On an additional page, I have the following:

`f.input :athlete, :collection => Athlete.all.sort_by(&:last_name), :required => true`

I would like to find a way to, if the `:notes` is not empty, display it.
If I could display it as a "row" on the form, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: You can check if Athlete have not any notes simply by `<% if !athlete.notes %>` do something `<% end %>`  assuming that athlete is passed as a local variable into the form. Remve the bang (!) to check if it *has* any notes

Comment: Thanks, I got it now.